# Performance breakdown for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a Rails model that has dozens of methods calling each other as follow:

```
class MyModel
 def function1
 end
 ...
 def functionN
 end

 def summary
   function1
   ...
   functionN
 end

end
```

I would like to check performance of summary and breakdown run time of each of methods it calls. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Profile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/profiler/rdoc/Profiler__.html) or use `-rprofile` in Ruby. Here's an excerpt:

> Just require ‘profile’:
>
> ```
> require 'profile'
>
> def slow_method
>   5000.times do
>     9999999999999999*999999999
>   end
> end
>
> def fast_method
>   5000.times do
>     9999999999999999+999999999
>   end
> end
>
> slow_method fast_method
> ```
>
> The output in both cases is a report when the execution is over:
>
> ```
> ruby -rprofile example.rb
>
>   %   cumulative   self              self     total  time   seconds  
> seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
>  68.42     0.13      0.13        2    65.00    95.00  Integer#times
>  15.79     0.16      0.03     5000     0.01     0.01  Fixnum#*
>  15.79     0.19      0.03     5000     0.01     0.01  Fixnum#+
>   0.00     0.19      0.00        2     0.00     0.00  IO#set_encoding
>   0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00   100.00  Object#slow_method
>   0.00     0.19      0.00        2     0.00     0.00  Module#method_added
>   0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00    90.00  Object#fast_method
>   0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00   190.00  #toplevel
> ```

So, you could add `require 'profile'` somewhere in your code (but it will significantly slow processing after that), and then when the Rails environment is exiting, it will output the profiling info. For your example, you might do in Rails console. First:

```
rails c
```

Then:

```
require 'profile'
MyModel.some_method_that_you_want_to_profile
exit
```

To filter, could do:

```
rails c 2>&1 | tee profile.txt
```

And then test as above, then after you are done:

```
grep MyModel profile.txt
```

Or include the headers and get rid of non-profiling output:

```
grep -E "MyModel\#|cumulative   self|seconds    call" profile.txt
```

If that is overkill, I'd suggest [benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) for just testing specific code blocks or methods.

See [performance testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html) in the guide for much more.

Also check out [ruby-prof](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof), but don't leave it in your Gemfile long-term- it seems to have seg faults when used with some other gems (e.g. using rspec-rails, simplecov, and ruby-prof together when running rspec tests -> seg faults for me).

And [Tracer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/index.html), [TracePoint](https://github.com/rubyunworks/tracepoint) (part of Ruby 2 now I think), [autolog](https://github.com/garysweaver/autolog), [set_trace_func](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/set_trace_func) etc. might help you see what is being called.

Comment: Gary: Thanks a lot for the materials. I looked at the performance testing before but it seems more for controller (although we can test models indirectly though calls to controller). Other gems/packages are relevant to my question. However, I am looking for something that does exactly what I want: keep track run time of a method and breakdown methods it calls. (I don't know if I am being greedy here :) )

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gary. Could you kindly explain how I can use `profile` in a Rails app?

Comment: Updated again. Hope that helps.